# Convergence in topological space to the point which has countable neighborgood

Tags: general-topology

Suppose x is the point of topological space X and x has countable neighborhood basis. Is it necessary existence of sequence in X-{x} which is convergence to x?

Comment: The standard interpretation as of content of your first sentence encompasses the case $X=\{x,y\}$, $\tau=\{\emptyset,\{x\},\{y\},\{x,y\}\}$.

Comment: And is the same result true, when the neighborhood is infinite countable?

Answer (score 1):

No: consider $\Bbb Z$ with the standard topology. All points are isolated.

Answer (score 0):

No, this happens iff $x$ is not an isolated point. If $x$ is isolated then $\{x\}$ is an open neighbourhood of $x$ and any sequence converging to $x$ must have $x_n =x$ from some index onwards.

And if $x$ is not isolated, let $(U_n)_n$ be a decreasing (in inclusion) neighbourhood base for $x$ and pick $x_n \in U_n\setminus \{x\}$ for every $n$, which is possible as $x$ is not isolated and then $ x_n \to x$.

Comment: How I can prove that?

Comment: @ErekleKhurodze I added a proof.